# In PHP, what is the difference between hash and mhash?

Tags: php, hash

I'm wondering what is the difference between the [hash extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php) and the [mhash extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mhash.php)?

When should I choose one over another and why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never mind, I just saw this on the [mhash Introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mhash.php).

> Note: This extension is obsoleted by
>   Hash.

Answer (score 6):

Mhash manual:

> This extension is obsoleted by Hash.